# Laravel query for multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, laravel, mongodb

I have collection in Laravel-Mongodb for Comments and this is the structure :
[image]

this is one comment with no reply but one comment may have multiple replies and as u can see count will be the reply numbers and edges field will have different arrays of replies like this :
[image]

this picture has 3 replies , i want to write a query which could be able to go through all 3 elements and get specific "id" values, i don't know how to do this!

```
$getUser = \App\Instacomment::where('comment.edge_threaded_comments.edges.node.owner.id' , $request->cm_thread)->get();
```

I wrote this query, but not working though, returns null

Comment: Please do it in two steps. 1. $getNodes = \App\Instacomment::where('comment.edge_threaded_comments.edges' , $request->cm_thread)->get(); 2. $getUser = Iterate over $getNodes and add the id to $getUser list. To make sure you are getting what you want from step 1 try var_dump($getNodes) to see whether you are getting all nodes.

Comment: "$request->cm_thread " has comment id and "$getNodes = \App\Instacomment::where('comment.edge_threaded_comments.edges' , $request->cm_thread)->get();" will return null! two steps is not good for performance, i have 11k comments in my database ...

Comment: The problem is in your where statement. You can filter out the comment with id first. Then you don't have to deal with 11k comments. Later, just simply loop through edges of the only comment you have retrieved.       where('comment.edge_threaded_comments.edges.node.owner.id' , $request->cm_thread). inside the where the left side value should match with the right side value. Then the where statement will work. But in your case you are trying to compare node.owner.id with comment id. Your correct comparison should be where( 'comment.id', $request->cm_thread) if cm_thread has the comment id.